# How to send SqlParameter to WCF where SQLParameter contains Bytes[]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, wcf

I am trying to send `SqlPrameter` to wcf service. The SqlParameter param which I am trying to send includes string,integer and Bytes (I am storing file in Database in varbinary). The

The following is the C# code I am using in my application:

```
Public Function InsertadanceClaimAttachMents(ByVal params As SqlParameter()) As Integer Implements IService.InsertadanceClaimAttachMents
       Dim i As Int16
       Try
           sql = ""
           sql = "Proc_InsertAdvanceClamAtt"

           i = Db.ExecProcedure(Declarations.ConnectionString, sql, params)
           Return i
       Catch ex As Exception
           Db.WriteErrorLog(ex, "Wcf_DBAccess.vb", "InsertadanceClaimAttachMents")
           Return 0
       End Try
   End Function
```

The following is the VB function I am using in my WCF service

```
  public bool insertAdvanceAttachments(Byte[] bytes, string filename, string ClaimNo, string mkrid)
       {
           Int32 I;
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
           cmd.Connection = con;
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           cmd.CommandText = "Proc_InsertAdvanceClamAtt";


           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", bytes);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgname", filename);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClaimNo", ClaimNo);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mkrid", mkrid);

           try
           {
               con.Open();
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               return true;
           }
           catch
           {
               return false;
           }
           //finally { con.Close(); }


           //try
           //{
           //    // string param, paramval;
           //    //param = "@img|@imgname|@ClaimNo|@mkrid";
           //    //paramval = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes).ToString() + "|" + filename + "|" + ClaimNo + "|" + mkrid;


           //    //SqlParameter[] param = { new SqlParameter("@img", bytes ), new SqlParameter("@imgname", filename), new SqlParameter("@ClaimNo", ClaimNo), new SqlParameter("@mkrid", mkrid) };


           //    SqlParameter[] param = { new SqlParameter("@img", SqlDbType.VarBinary, bytes.Length, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "Data", DataRowVersion.Current, (SqlBinary)bytes), new SqlParameter("@imgname", filename), new SqlParameter("@ClaimNo", ClaimNo), new SqlParameter("@mkrid", mkrid) };

           //    I = baz_obj.InsertadanceClaimAttachMents(param);
           //    return true;
           //}
           //catch (Exception ex)
           //{
           //    return false;
           //}
           return true;
       }
```

The problem is that I am not even able to get to the WCF service get following error:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:params.
>   The InnerException message was 'Type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary' with data contract name 'base64Binary:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details

**UPDATE**

```
SqlParameter[] param = { new SqlParameter("@img", SqlDbType.VarBinary), new SqlParameter("@imgname", SqlDbType.VarChar), new SqlParameter("@ClaimNo", SqlDbType.VarChar), new SqlParameter("@mkrid", SqlDbType.VarChar) };
           param[0].Value = bytes;
           param[1].Value = filename;
           param[2].Value = ClaimNo;
           param[3].Value = mkrid;
```

Comment: What is the parameter type you set for `@img`?

Comment: Are you trying to send a SqlParameter by WCF? That's a terrible idea. This is going to be a gigantic security issue and I'm pretty sure a SQLParameter is not serialisable. Just send your **data** to your service and let that create the SqlParameters

Comment: Your abstractions are leaking...

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim data As byte()
Dim parameter As New SqlParameter("@Param1", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
parameter.Value = data
```

you can use SqlDbType.Image instead of SqlDbType.VarBinary

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3406432/3761928) also not the same question but you can get your answer from here.

Comment: this does not address the WCF issue. Even if the OP added this code, his methodology still will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Set your parameter type to `VarBinary`

```
SQLParameter param1=new SqlParameter("@img",SqlDbType.VarBinary);
param1.Value=bytes
param.Add(param1);
param.AddRange(etc);
```

Check [Data type mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)